# Angular to Aurelia Transition - Some basic questions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, aurelia

We are thinking about using Aurelia for a new app. I come from an Angular 1 background (with some exposure to Angular 2). Aurelia seems quite nice and I really like how they have taken on the responsibility of maintaining developer workflow. However I have some questions which I cannot seem to find the answers to:

1) There are two general ways (as I understand) that one can include a web component in a page. These are `<compose>` and write a custom element. My question is, coming from Angular there is a big emphasis on scopes (i.e. what is in scope at a specific point in the DOM). I am wondering what is in "scope" (i.e. available to binding expression) withing compose and custom elements. I mean, is a parent view-model available within a child template? If so, do child view-model properties hide/shadow the parent view-model properties?

2) In Angular 2, there are guidelines with respect to how data is passed in and out of components. We are not supposed to change non-primitives that are bound to a component (because that forces Angular 2's change detection to always go into that component branch to check all properties).

Are there any guidelines/info to passing data in and out of components in Aurelia? I mean from the reading that I have done it sounds like I would just use `value.bind` to bind to all the `@bindable` properties. Is that correct? Are these two-way bound by default or do I have to explicitly declare `value.two-way`? Is there anything wrong with changing the properties of a two-way bound object?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Great questions- here's some info:

> 1) There are two general ways (as I understand) that one can include a web component in a page. These are `<compose>` and write a custom element. My question is, coming from Angular there is a big emphasis on scopes (i.e. what is in scope at a specific point in the DOM). I am wondering what is in "scope" (i.e. available to binding expression) within compose and custom elements. I mean, is a parent view-model available within a child template? If so, do child view-model properties hide/shadow the parent view-model properties?

Consider the following markup:

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <h1>${message}</h1>

  <date-picker value.bind="startDate"></date-picker>

  <compose view="footer.html"></compose>
<template>
```

**`<compose>` preserves access to the outer scope.** When the template contained in `footer.html` is data-bound, it will have access to whatever `app.html` is bound to- for example, it could access the `message` property.

**A custom element's template cannot access the outer scope.** Custom elements are intended to be encapsulated and portable. For this reason they are not allowed to access the outer scope, preventing developers from creating custom elements that expect to be used in specific binding contexts.  The primary way to get data in/out of a custom element is through `@bindable` properties (similar to dependency-properties in XAML).

> 2) In Angular 2, there are guidelines with respect to how data is passed in and out of components. We are not supposed to change non-primitives that are bound to a component (because that forces Angular 2's change detection to always go into that component branch to check all properties).
>
> Are there any guidelines/info to passing data in and out of components in Aurelia? I mean from the reading that I have done it sounds like I would just use `value.bind` to bind to all the `@bindable` properties. Is that correct?

**correct**

> Are these two-way bound by default or do I have to explicitly declare `value.two-way`? Is there anything wrong with changing the properties of a two-way bound object?

Aurelia automatically chooses the correct default binding mode for attributes of *built-in elements* like inputs or selects. You need to specify the defaults for *custom elements* if you want something other than `one-way`. Here's how to do that:

```js
import {bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework'; // or 'aurelia-binding';

export class DatePicker {
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) value;  // <----
  @bindable min = new Date(1900, 0, 1);
  @bindable max = new Date(2250, 11, 31);
  ...
}
```

Comment: " `<compose>` preserves access to the outer scope". I didn't know that! Very interesting, as all of your answers! master Jeremy

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I assume then, that properties in child view-models shadow/hide the same properties on parents. Is that correct? In other words if both the child and parent have model properties then if I bind to the model property in the child template it will only change child.model but not parent.model. Is that correct?

Comment: right- a prop in the current scope will be preferred over a prop with the same name in the outer scope.  To explicitly access the outer scope use `$parent.someProperty`.  To explicitly access the outer-outer-outer scope use `$parent.$parent.$parent.someProperty`.

Comment: @JeremyDanyow One more question: If I two way bind an object model  and change model.prop in the child will that change be rendered in the parent (i.e. will Aurelia know that the property was changed)? If I one way bind an object and change prop in the child will that change be propogated to the parent (do the two variables refer to the same model object) and will the change actually trigger a rendering in the parent template?

Comment: yes- for example if you had `${foo.bar.baz} <my-component.bind="foo">...` and inside of `my-component` you changed `foo.bar` the interpolation binding expression on the other end would update.

Comment: @JeremyDanyow Question - does `compose` preserve access to the outer scope if the `model` property is used? Offhand, my guess is yes....but I'm guessing that the properties would only be available in the view, and not the viewmodel itself (unless you explicitly inject the binding context).

Comment: In all cases the context is preserved.  Model is ultimately an argument for activate

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<compose>` as a wildcard declaration. So instead of declaring the web component, like `<my-component></my-component>` you can do

```
<compose view-model.bind="variableContainingModel" model.bind="variableContainingViewModelPath"></compose>
```

or just

```
<compose view-model="./my-component.html" model="./my-component.js"></compose>
```

> **Update from Jeremy Danyow's answer**
>
> The compose tag preserves access to the outer scope. When the template
>   is data-bound, it will have access to its parent's properties.

A custom component sees all properties declared in its view-model. If you want to share any parent view-model object to the component, you can use bindable properties.

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
export class MyComponent {
   @bindable propertyFromMyParent;
}
```

view:

```
<template>
   <div>${propertyFromMyParent}</div>
</template>

//parent call
<my-component propertyFromMyParent.bind="someProperty"></my-component>
```

Bindable properties are one-way by default. You can override this using:

```
import {bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';
@bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) propertyFromMyParent
```

There is also the `content` tag which very useful:

```
<template>
   <content></content>
</template>

//parent call
<my-component>Some Content Here</my-component>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Fabio, thanks for the response. I did not know about the content tag. What view models are scoped in the content tag? Can I access child and parent view models inside the content? It would seem that I could...

Comment: `<compose view-model.bind="variableContainingModel" view-model.bind="variableContainingViewModelPath"></compose>` will not work because you have view-model.bind twice??

Comment: Sorry, I meant `view-model.bind` and `view.bind`. It is correct now