# Aurelia oneTime binding as defaultBindingMode

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am trying to do something like this:

```
bindable({defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.oneTime}) options = {};
```

and getting a warning in the browser's console:

```
WARN [templating-binding] Unknown binding command. Object {defaultBindingMode: 1, attrName: "route-href", attrValue: "navModel.config.name", command: "onetime", expression: null}
```

Shouldn't I be able to specify that the options parameter (which is really only used once in `attached()` ) should only be bound one time by default?

Comment: Need more info- please include an example of how you are using the bindable property in your html template. For a better answer include a running example: https://gist.run/?id=7542e061bc940cde506b

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the inline syntax of bindable in the way you're attempting. You need to use the more verbose syntax and decorate the class.

```
@bindable({
    name: 'options',
    defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.oneTime,
    defaultValue: {}
});
export class MyViewModel {
...
}
```

The syntax for `@bindable` is as follows (right from the documentation):

```
@bindable({
  name:'myProperty',
  attribute:'my-property',
  changeHandler:'myPropertyChanged',
  defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.oneWay,
  defaultValue: undefined
})
```

Comment: Jeremy Danyow seems to think differently in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879520/angular-to-aurelia-transition-some-basic-questions

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it this way;

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework'
import {bindingMode} from 'aurelia-binding'

@bindable({name:'foo', defaultBindingMode : bindingMode.oneTime})
export class Elem{
  foo;
}
```

Or you can do it in-line:

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework'
import {bindingMode} from 'aurelia-binding'

export class Elem{
  @bindable({name:'foo', defaultBindingMode : bindingMode.twoWay}) foo;
}
```

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d9EXNNoYixWB6J4bqomI?p=preview) with the code that *should* work. But there is a bug at this, `oneTime` is ignored when used as a `defaultBindingMode`. See [this issue](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/298) I have just reported.

Comment: Jeremy Danyow seems to think differently in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879520/angular-to-aurelia-transition-some-basic-questions

Comment: It works in-line as well. See [this updated plunkr] http://plnkr.co/edit/Vh7GucadgbfU6mDhkwk5?p=preview. I've used `twoWay` instead of `oneTime` there but it's the same